# How to select all math equations in documents with VBA in MS word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm quite new to the VBA editor in MS word and I was wondering if there is a way to select all math equations in a word document using VBA?
For example, the following code

```
Sub Change_Equation_Color()
Dim Eq As OMath
For Each Eq In ActiveDocument.OMaths
Eq.Range.Select
Selection.Font.ColorIndex = wdDarkBlue '
Next
End Sub
```

Selects each math equation in sequence and changes each equation's color to 'wdDarkBlue'. Even though this is fine, is there a way to first select all equations and then change the color/font/etc of the selection? The main reason is that if my document has a lot of equations, then the provided code is a little slow, since it has to go through every equation sequentially.

**EDIT**. @Timothy Rylatt has provided a pretty fast & general method, but for my purpose, I found that the following code is actually much faster.

```
Sub Eq2LM()
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Format = False
        .Font.Name = "Cambria Math"
        .Text = ""
       
        With .Replacement
            .ClearFormatting
            .Font.Name = "Latin Modern Math"
            .Text = ""
        End With
        .Execute Forward:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

The "caveat" is that your equations must all be of the font "Cambria math", which is usually the default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to create a non-contiguous selection using VBA.

It is not good practice to use the `Selection` object, although very occasionally it is necessary. There are usually much better alternatives which are more efficient and less error prone. For example:

```
Sub Change_Equation_Color()
    Dim Eq As OMath
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each Eq In ActiveDocument.OMaths
        Eq.Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdDarkBlue
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I see. In that case, would it possible to change the font/color of all equations at once (without selecting). For example, I can change the font of all "normal" styled text by just modifying the font used in the "normal" style.

Comment: @AndrewYuan - there isn't a default style for equations, so, unless you have applied a specific style only to equations, there isn't a similar shortcut. The routine in my answer will run several times faster than the one in your question because it doesn't select anything or cause the screen to be redrawn for each equation it finds.